# How to export Core Data sqlite to iCloud and import back for new devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, icloud-drive

I'm developing core data based app and want to implement iCloud so that user can recover data from iCloud if he lost device and bought new one.
I enabled iCloud capability and iCloud documents(I'm currently using `NSPersistentContainer`, I don't want to use `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` yet)

I know iOS 13 provides way to sync Core Data with iCloud but I think that doesn't seem to be ready for production app yet(Migration doesn't work well)

So I want to back up core data to iCloud every 24 horus to iCloud and when user installs app in new device we can check if iCloud has existing sqlite file and restore it if there is any.

Could anyone please suggest good solution?
Thanks.

Comment: did you get any answer ?I also want to Export Core data Sqlite database from device to System through mail or any other option.I tried adding sqlite as attachment but it is always empty.No records are there in any table.